# Spring boot maven multiple module project: Compilation failure cannot find symbol

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, maven-module

I created a multiple module spring boot project with a parent pom. 
In the module test-data, i added some Entities-Classes User and Login:

```
@Table
@Entity
public class Login implements Serializable {
    ... another column
    @Column(unique = true, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(50)", nullable = false)
    private String username;
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "login")
    private User user;
    // getter and setter
```

The User class:

```
@Table
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable{
...
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "login_id")
    private Login login;
...
```

The pom.xml of module test-data:

```
 <parent>
        <groupId>com.emo.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>emo-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>test-data</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        // other dependencies
    </dependencies>
```

The main class of test-data:

```
package com.test;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }
```

The main class of test-oauth:

```
package com.oauth.server;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class OAuthApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OAuthApplication.class, args);
    }
```

I added the module test-data in the second module test-oauth as dependency like this:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.emo.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>emo-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>test-oauth</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>test-oauth</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.emo.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>test-data</artifactId>
            <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                    <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Into the module test-oauth, i use the entity User:

```
@Transactional
@Service("userServiceImpl")
public class UserServiceImpl {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public User findByUsername(String username) throws EmptyResultDataAccessException {
        String query = "FROM Login l WHERE l.username = :username";
        final Login l = (Login) entityManager.createQuery(query).setParameter("username", username).getSingleResult();
        return l.getUser();
    }
}
```

I got this exception: `Compilation failure: Compilation failure: cannot find symbol User,  package com.test.core.entities does not exist`

My Parent pom.xml

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.emo.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>emo-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>test-data</module>
        <module>test-oauth</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.11</java.version>
        <oauth.version>2.2.2.RELEASE</oauth.version>
        <kazi.data.version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</kazi.data.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>${oauth.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-plugin-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: Check are you use static import for user or not . Try to run with console command also

Comment: no use static import

Comment: I'm missing the packaging entry in module test-data

Comment: It would be easy if you can provide the whole error log. 
Also please mention the below value used for ${test.data.version} and maven command you used

Comment: @royB the packaging of both is jar. chathura rupasinghe mistake

Comment: multimodules are hard to debug. please add `main` class for both modules which shows all annotation on them and package declaration

Comment: @Hemant i added the main class of both

Comment: Are each of the modules working independently? If not then you're probably not scanning the entities in on one of the modules. Provide the error message from `maven`. Then at least we know which module is breaking. Is module A trying to import something from module B?

Comment: yep, i use the a service from module A in module B

Comment: I fixed it but i have another error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61715489/spring-boot-multiple-module-project-org-hibernate-hql-internal-ast-querysyntaxex

Comment: Hi @emoleumassi, do you mind sharing how you fixed it. I am running into a similar issue.